# std::filesystem fails on Windows (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, c++17, std-filesystem

The following code throws an exception when compiled on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 but runs fine on POSIX OS (macOS, Linux):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
 
int main()
{
    auto p = std::filesystem::path("*");
    try
    {
        std::cout << std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(p) << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "exception\n";
    }
}
```

The asterix can be replaced by a question mark or a colon (maybe other characters) to throw the exception under Windows. How can I deal with (potentially) non existing paths including these characters independently of the OS ?

Comment: Fixed since MSVC `v19.22` https://godbolt.org/z/3YY7WxGa8 `Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.2`

Comment: "The overload that does not take a std::error_code& parameter throws filesystem::filesystem_error on underlying OS API errors, constructed with p as the first path argument and the OS error code as the error code argument. The overload taking a std::error_code& parameter sets it to the OS API error code if an OS API call fails, and executes ec.clear() if no errors occur. Any overload not marked noexcept may throw std::bad_alloc if memory allocation fails. "

Comment: But good see the behavior is more consistent now.

Comment: @Marek: Great news, and thanks for making me know godbolt !

Comment: I recommend watching talks from Matt Godbolt for example [this](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).